# Deployement of JBPM_6_0_1 in alfresco's tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, alfresco, jbpm

I have installed Alfresco Community Edition. Now I have to install JBPM 6 in alfresco's tomcat,so that I can access both application on same port like http://localhost:8080/share/page ,http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console-6-0-1/
 Can We do this.
How?

Comment: Which version of Alfresco did you install? And what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why are you trying to install JBPM into Alfresco? Alfresco already ships with both JBPM and Activiti workflow engines built in!

Comment: I think JBPM was actually removed.
https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-6297-alfresco-community-edition-201605-ga-release-notes

Comment: Actually We need to access Alfresco 1.0.0 and jbpm6 using same port number. So I decided to deploy both application on same server. But alfresco's tomcat is highly configured . Finally I got success to deploy JBPM in alfresco's tomcat.